# Skip Video time slider Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying the fast-forward the video by some time using selenium. The HTML tag looks like below:

```
<span class="mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider" style="width: 895px;" aria-label="Time Slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="83.733333" aria-valuenow="4.22" aria-valuetext="00:04" role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="mejs-time-buffering" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="mejs-time-loaded" style="width: 269.633px;"></span>
    <span class="mejs-time-current" style="width: 45px;"></span>
    <span class="mejs-time-handle" style="left: 38px;"></span>
    <span class="mejs-time-float" style="display: none;">
        <span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span>
        <span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="mejs-time-current" style="width: 45px;"></span>
```

Trying to manipulate the value but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
WebElement element = context.getDriver()
    .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getContext().getDriver();
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('width', '240');", element);
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like bare HTML is not enough to reproduce the issue: the snippet you added doesn't contain any video. Please add the missing pieces so that others can help. Best regards

Comment: It would be better to post a link to an example page that contains a video with the controls that you are trying to manipulate.